# CAS switch the themes based on different services

Tags: cas

Trying to configure a custom theme based on the service has been quite an undertaking in CAS 6.2.0.  We use the car-overlay-template (https://github.com/apereo/cas-overlay-template) to configure and build the project.

The documentation is pretty clear about where to put the themes and what properties to use in the cas.properties file:  https://apereo.github.io/cas/development/ux/User-Interface-Customization-Views.html

The property value to specify the templates location is set to:

```
#spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
#spring.thymeleaf.prefix=file:///etc/cas/templates/
cas.view.templatePrefixes=file:///etc/cas/templates/
```

and I have the appropriate directory in the templates directory above specified in the service configuration but I continue to get the error:

```
2020-04-19 06:35:06,268 WARN [org.apereo.cas.services.web.RegisteredServiceThemeResolver] - <Custom theme [foobar] for service [AbstractRegisteredService(serviceId=^(https|imaps)://.*, name=HTTPS and IMAPS, theme=epc, informationUrl=null, privacyUrl=null, responseType=null, id=10000001, description=This service definition authorizes all application urls that support HTTPS and IMAPS protocols., expirationPolicy=DefaultRegisteredServiceExpirationPolicy(deleteWhenExpired=false, notifyWhenDeleted=false, notifyWhenExpired=false, expirationDate=null), acceptableUsagePolicy=DefaultRegisteredServiceAcceptableUsagePolicy(enabled=true, messageCode=null, text=null), proxyPolicy=org.apereo.cas.services.RefuseRegisteredServiceProxyPolicy@1, proxyTicketExpirationPolicy=null, proxyGrantingTicketExpirationPolicy=null, serviceTicketExpirationPolicy=null, singleSignOnParticipationPolicy=null, evaluationOrder=10000, usernameAttributeProvider=org.apereo.cas.services.DefaultRegisteredServiceUsernameProvider@87297e2, logoutType=BACK_CHANNEL, environments=[], attributeReleasePolicy=ReturnAllowedAttributeReleasePolicy(super=AbstractRegisteredServiceAttributeReleasePolicy(attributeFilter=null, principalAttributesRepository=DefaultPrincipalAttributesRepository(), consentPolicy=DefaultRegisteredServiceConsentPolicy(enabled=true, excludedAttributes=null, includeOnlyAttributes=null, order=0), authorizedToReleaseCredentialPassword=false, authorizedToReleaseProxyGrantingTicket=false, excludeDefaultAttributes=false, authorizedToReleaseAuthenticationAttributes=true, principalIdAttribute=null, order=0), allowedAttributes=[]), multifactorPolicy=DefaultRegisteredServiceMultifactorPolicy(multifactorAuthenticationProviders=[], failureMode=UNDEFINED, principalAttributeNameTrigger=null, principalAttributeValueToMatch=null, bypassEnabled=false, forceExecution=false, bypassTrustedDeviceEnabled=false, bypassPrincipalAttributeName=null, bypassPrincipalAttributeValue=null, script=null), logo=null, logoutUrl=null, redirectUrl=null, accessStrategy=DefaultRegisteredServiceAccessStrategy(order=0, enabled=true, ssoEnabled=true, unauthorizedRedirectUrl=null, delegatedAuthenticationPolicy=DefaultRegisteredServiceDelegatedAuthenticationPolicy(allowedProviders=[], permitUndefined=true, exclusive=false), requireAllAttributes=true, requiredAttributes={}, rejectedAttributes={}, caseInsensitive=false), publicKey=null, authenticationPolicy=DefaultRegisteredServiceAuthenticationPolicy(requiredAuthenticationHandlers=[], criteria=null), properties={}, contacts=[])] cannot be located. Falling back to default theme...>
```

Nowhere in the documentation does it mention directory structure for the theme/filenames or format.  I understand the project is using Thymeleaf but we still need filenames and I guess a better understanding of how to set the theme path so the CAS can find the theme.

If you had any luck configuring this it would be great if you shared the part of your configuration we are missing.

Answer (score 0):

After a LOT of testing and playing around with the configuration I finally got it to work as I expected it to work.  I have put a small project together just in case someone else had this issue and needs a quick tutorial.  You can see the project at:  https://github.com/dannymk/cas-dynamic-style